# Failed to resolve 3DR Services library dependency while syncing Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, dronekit, dronekit-android

I'm working through [this example](http://android.dronekit.io/first_app.html) on the DroneKit Android documentation website. When I sync the Gradle after adding the 3DR Services library dependency "com.o3dr.android:droneKit-android:2.3.11", I receive:

```
Error:(24,13): Failed to resolve: com.o3dr.android:droneKit-android:2.3.11.
```

I've checked the dependencies under Project Structure and Android Studio appears to find the library but I still receive this error when syncing the Gradle. I have also tried adding MavenCentral to my repositories but Studio still cannot locate the library files.

Here are the relevant gradle scripts:

Project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matt.hellodrone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.o3dr.android:droneKit-android:2.3.11'}
```

Any pointers on troubleshooting this issue would be appreciated. I'm still pretty new to Android Studio! Thank you.

Comment: The error is just a minor typo. It should be `dronekit-android` instead of `droneKit-android` (no uppercase `K`).

Comment: @ne0fhyk Thank you! Can't believe I missed that. My problem has been resolved.

Comment: You should validate the right answer, instead of adding "Resolved" in the title. By the way, ne0fhyk should have answered the question instead of writing his answer as a comment...

Answer (score 2):

There's (still) a typo in the tutorial. Should be:

```
compile 'com.o3dr.android:dronekit-android:2.3.11'
```

(small 'k')